Creating websocket proxy
i want to create a websocket proxy which connect client in browser to a docker container. The docker host is open on tcp and am using dockerode which is JS sdk for docker.
The requirement is to start an exec shell in the container and use that to read and write.
i am able to create the exec process in the container but am not able to stream data to and from the client to container.
wss.on("connection", async (ws) => {
  const container = docker.getContainer("76941c597e89");
  console.log("client connected");
  const exec = await container.exec({
    Cmd: ["/bin/sh"],
    AttachStdin: true,
    AttachStdout: true,
    User: "root",
  });
  exec.start({ Tty: true, hijack: true }, (err, stream) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
    stream?.on("data", (data) => {
      ws.send(data.toString());
    });
    ws.on("message", (msg) => {
      stream?.emit("data", msg);
    });
  });
});


Are you sure that stream?.emit('data', msg) doesn't trigger the stream?.on('data') handler (thereby, probably, starting an infinite loop between the two stream handlers)?

if that is true then i should see infinit text on my client side which i donot see , so i think that is not the case.

You shouldn't need docker exec or any other Docker-specific logic in your application.  If the backend service is listening on a TCP port, you can use ordinary Docker inter-container networking to connect to it, or if the service is running directly on the host, it can connect to a docker run -p published port.

I got it working

@Anish if you got it working, please answer your own question, or remove it if it was because of a typo or something local.

I got it working. This is the final code.


wss.on("connection", async (ws, req) => {
  const CONTAINER_ID = req.url?.split("=")[1];
  try {
    const container = docker.getContainer(CONTAINER_ID as string);
    const exec = await container.exec({
      Cmd: ["/bin/sh"],
      AttachStdin: true,
      AttachStdout: true,
      User: "root",
      Tty: true,
    });
    const stream = await exec.start({
      stdin: true,
      hijack: true,
      Detach: false,
    });
    stream.on("data", (data) => {
      ws.send(data.toString());
    });
    ws.on("message", (msg) => {
      stream.write(msg);
    });
    ws.on("close", async () => {
      stream.write("exit\n");
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    ws.close();
  }
});



